# What are hadronic uncertainties?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

I am reading articles about recent findings at CERN and the possibility of *New Physics* contributions, and they keep saying that the discrepancies may be due to ***hadronic uncertainties***...

What are they? How do they come about?

Comment: Can you post a link to the article, please? I think it would be easier to give a comprehensive answer, if we knew the context.

Comment: I'm not sure that the phrase has a precisely defined meaning. I've seen it used where QCD calculations are difficult, e.g. because the system is strongly interacting, so the properties of the system can't be calculated with much accuracy.

Comment: We don't know how to solve QCD. At high energies, we can use an perturbative expansion, but our prediction will be limited to the order of expansion we have considered (LO, NLO, NNLO etc). At low energies, where QCD is notoriously non-perturbativity, the best we can do is numerical simulations with Lattice QCD methods. In this case, our predictions are limited to the errors of our Monte Carlo Simulation. So, in both scenarios there are uncertainties coming from the fact that we don't know how to solve exactly QCD